# Валидация формы checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Не могу найти ошибку, условия вроде правильные, но не выводит сообщение об ошибке. `Checked = FALSE` - выводим сообщение об ошибке, иначе `ELSE` - отправляем данные.

```
    $('#phone').mask('+7 (000) 000-00-00');
$("#form-feedback").submit(function(event) {
    if ($('#name').val() == "")
        {
            $('#bthrow_error_name').fadeIn(1000).html('Представьтесь, пожалуйста.');
        }
    else if ($('#phone').val() == "")
        {
            $('#bthrow_error_name').empty();
            $('#bthrow_error_phone').fadeIn(1000).html('Как с Вами связаться?');
        }
    else if ($('#lisenze').is(':checked') == 'false')
        {
            $('#bthrow_error_dan').fadeIn(1000).html('Дайте согласие на обработку конфеденциальных данных!');
        }
    else
        {
            var postForm = {
                'name'  : $('#name').val(),
                'phone'  : $('#phone').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST',
                url         : '/templates/feedback.php',
                data        : postForm,
                dataType    : 'json',
                success     : function(data)
                    {
                        if (!data.success)
                            {
                                if (data.errors.name)
                                    {
                                        $('.throw_error').fadeIn(1000).html(data.errors.name);
                                    }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $('#form-feedback').fadeIn(1000).html('<p>' + data.posted + '</p>');
                            }
                    }
            });
        }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Comment: Здравствуйте! В коде видимо закрывающих скобок не хватает. Исправьте ваш код, а пока я вам минус за вопрос поставлю, как исправите - с радостью уберу.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov специально для Вас вывел весь код. Что вы имеете ввиду под закрывающемися скобками не понимаю. Напишите номер строки я поправлю!

Comment: Не специально для меня, а ради себя вы это сделали, т.к. если код рабочий, это значительно повышает ваши шансы найти ответ. Спасибо вам **ggLike**, убираю минус.